Is there a possibility for wget to handle long(er) paths?
I am using wget for a local backup of a remote ftp/s directory using the following syntax:
wget --no-dns-cache -nv -r -c -l inf -P/local_dir -nH --cut-dirs=1 --restrict-file-names=windows --progress=dot:mega --ftps-implicit (...)

This is wget 1.21 on Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
# wget --version
GNU Wget 1.21 built on linux-gnueabihf.

I am restricting file names to 'windows' because the local directory is shared via smb to a Windows PC.
The problem I encountered is that some files inside the remote directory tree have long paths.
In such a case, wget prints (for instance):
The name is too long, 240 chars total.
Trying to shorten...

and it downloads the file with its name shortened.
If a local filesystem has no support for long paths, this behaviour is some necessary workaround and is appreciated.
However, in my case, the local filesystem does support long paths. I can create paths much longer than 240 characters with mkdir, cp, mc, and so on. So the name length restriction introduced by wget is unnecessary and causes problems: some files end up without extensions, some names are cut at the dot ('.') character and then their names are not showing properly via smb.
Is there a parameter enabling wget to use longer path names?

I am using wget in entirely in linux. Then the linux local_dir directory is shared to a windows PC via smb share, so windows is not an issue here (but windows has no problem with handling long paths in this scenario, anyway).

You can still modify the source

True. I think I'll try this.

Can you show the actual filename? Windows filesystems uses UTF-16 so it's possible to have a 240-character long name that's longer than 255 bytes when converting to UTF-8. Too long name and too long path are very different, although Windows can cope with both

Again. Wget is run entirely in linux and on a linux partition. Windows is out of question here (it only reads the linux partition as a smb share).

but did you read my comment? Is the name longer than 255 UTF-8 codepoints? That's the important point and has nothing to do with Windows. The error is The name is too long, not The path is too long.  And to address anyone on stackexchange you have to use @username or they won't receive the notification

Here is a test name with full path on the server:
_tst\67_10_234567_20_234567_30_234567_40_234567_50_234567_60_234567_70_234567_80_234567_90_23456_100_23456_110_23456_120_234\6_130_23456_140_23456_150_23456_160_23456_170_23456_180_23456_190_23456_200_23456_210_23456_220_23456_230_23456.240
As you can see, the full path is 240 chars long and this is how it is reported by wget.
The filename by itself is 114 chars long.

Wget is clearly reporting the length of the full path (including ''). For the test, I shortened the (mentioned above) filename, cutting off the last char. Wget reported: 'The name is too long, 239 chars total.'

I was cutting off last chars one by one. The last 'too long' message was at 237. The path of 236 characters (with the filename of 110 chars long) is downloaded OK, without a 'too long' message.

As I mentioned before, I am using the --restrict-file-names=windows flag (so as to ensure the filenames will be readable via smb). I had a wild guess that this might cause my problem. But no. I tried invoking without this flag and with different values: unix and ascii. The effect was always the same - the file name was truncated each time when its full path length was over 236 chars. Strange number, BTW.

Moreover, I tried lftp mirror command. I checked it with files of path lenght up to 484 chars. The files were transferred succesfully (tried in both directions) and without truncated names. So this is a wget's "feature".

I thought of replacing wget with lftp in my backup script, but I like the unique feature of wget - restriction of filenames to conform windows naming.
Additionally, wget is MUCH faster... no idea, why.
